# How to utilize command line values in a loop

Tags: c, factorial, argc

My code is supposed to get the factorial of a passed value. I spoke with my professor and he told me to use int argc, char* argv[] arguments. It compiles but will loop once and will only return the initial value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int fact = 1;
   if(argc>1)
   { 
        printf("Too many inputs!\n");
        return -1;
   }
   int n = atoi(argv[1]);
   for(int i = 1; i <= n;i++)
   {
       fact *= i; 
   }
   printf("%d\n", fact);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: where did the '5' come from?

Comment: Also, you should check `argc > 1` before calling `atoi`.

Comment: FYI, this parameter is almost always called `argv`, not `aragv`.

Comment: 5 was an int i put in. I removed it because i can't figure out how to implement argv[] without something between the brackets, it causes an error.

Comment: If you only pass one command line parameter, it's `argv[1]`, not `argv[5]`.

Comment: *Note:* You probably don't want to modify `n` while you're also using it in your loop's condition.

Comment: It should be `fact *= i`, you don't need to reassign `n`.

Comment: Updated the code and it just returns the input value

Comment: `atoi` has bad error handling and should never be used for that purpose, particularly not on command-line input. Use `strtol` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Explain..

In the C language, main **argv[0]** always contains the program filename, **argv[1]** is your first commandline parameter.

argc is like an array count from 0, so

If you have **argc=1**, you have no commandline parameters.

If you have **argc=2**, you have *one* commandline parameter.

Check out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm

Answer (score 1):

Heres how to read the command line to get one integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if(argc != 2){
       printf("wrong arguments\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
   int n = atoi(argv[1]);
   printf("you entered %d\n", n);
   return 0;
}
```

note that this does not deal with the case where there is 'frog' instead of '42' on the command line. I leave that up to you to work out